# Todos los fragmentos almacenados en el stack del fragment manager se muestran al girar la pantalla del dispositivo - Android Studio

Tags: android-studio, android-fragment

Estoy haciendo una aplicacion sobre resolucion de metodos numericos, en mi primera pantalla tengo el siguiente diseño:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Codigo xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

<data>
    <variable name="datos" type="com.example.metodosnumericos.view_model.metodo_biseccion.ModelBiseccion" />
    <variable name="evento" type="com.example.metodosnumericos.view_model.metodo_biseccion.ModelBiseccion" />
</data>

<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    android:id="@+id/contentMain"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:id="@+id/constraintLayout"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/constraintLayout6"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHeight_default="percent"
        app:layout_constraintHeight_percent=".15"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_chainStyle="spread"
        app:layout_constraintWidth_default="percent"
        app:layout_constraintWidth_percent=".8">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:text="@string/txtView_Funcion"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/edtxt_Funcion"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHeight_default="percent"
            app:layout_constraintHeight_percent=".4"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintVertical_chainStyle="packed"
            app:layout_constraintWidth_default="percent"
            app:layout_constraintWidth_percent="1" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/edtxt_Funcion"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:background="@drawable/edittext"
            android:digits="0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz()^/*-+"
            android:ems="10"
            android:hint="@string/edtxtHint_Funcion"
            android:importantForAutofill="no"
            android:inputType="text"
            android:paddingStart="20dp"
            android:paddingEnd="20dp"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:text="@={datos.funcion}"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHeight_default="percent"
            app:layout_constraintHeight_percent=".6"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView"
            app:layout_constraintWidth_default="percent" />

    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:id="@+id/constraintLayout7"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHeight_default="percent"
        app:layout_constraintHeight_percent=".15"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/constraintLayout5"
        app:layout_constraintWidth_default="percent"
        app:layout_constraintWidth_percent=".8">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn_Calcular"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:background="@drawable/button_calcular"
            android:onClick='@{()->evento.setOnListener("Calcular")}'
            android:text="@string/btnCalcular"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHeight_default="percent"
            app:layout_constraintHeight_percent=".6"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/btn_Nuevo"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintWidth_default="percent"
            app:layout_constraintWidth_percent=".48" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn_Nuevo"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:background="@drawable/button_nuevo"
            android:onClick='@{()->evento.setOnListener("Nuevo")}'
            android:text="@string/btnNuevo"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/btn_Calcular"
            app:layout_constraintHeight_default="percent"
            app:layout_constraintHeight_percent=".6"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintWidth_default="percent"
            app:layout_constraintWidth_percent=".48" />
    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:id="@+id/constraintLayout6"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/constraintLayout5"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHeight_default="percent"
        app:layout_constraintHeight_percent=".15"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/constraintLayout"
        app:layout_constraintWidth_default="percent"
        app:layout_constraintWidth_percent=".8">

        <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
            android:id="@+id/constraintLayout2"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHeight_default="percent"
            app:layout_constraintHeight_percent="1"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintWidth_default="percent"
            app:layout_constraintWidth_percent=".48">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView2"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:gravity="center_vertical"
                android:text="@string/txtView_LimiteA"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/edtxt_ValorInicial"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintHeight_default="percent"
                app:layout_constraintHeight_percent=".4"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintVertical_chainStyle="packed"
                app:layout_constraintWidth_default="percent"
                app:layout_constraintWidth_percent="1" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/edtxt_ValorInicial"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:background="@drawable/edittext"
                android:digits="0123456789."
                android:ems="10"
                android:hint="@string/edtxtHint_LimiteA"
                android:importantForAutofill="no"
                android:inputType="numberDecimal"
                android:paddingStart="20dp"
                android:paddingEnd="20dp"
                android:singleLine="true"
                android:text="@={datos.limiteA}"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintHeight_default="percent"
                app:layout_constraintHeight_percent=".6"
                app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView2"
                app:layout_constraintWidth_default="percent"
                app:layout_constraintWidth_percent="1" />

        </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

        <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
            android:id="@+id/constraintLayout3"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHeight_default="percent"
            app:layout_constraintHeight_percent="1"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="1"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0"
            app:layout_constraintWidth_default="percent"
            app:layout_constraintWidth_percent=".48">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView3"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:gravity="center_vertical"
                android:text="@string/txtView_LimiteB"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/edtxt_LimiteB"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintHeight_default="percent"
                app:layout_constraintHeight_percent=".4"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintVertical_chainStyle="packed"
                app:layout_constraintWidth_default="percent"
                app:layout_constraintWidth_percent="1" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/edtxt_LimiteB"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:background="@drawable/edittext"
                android:digits="0123456789."
                android:ems="10"
                android:hint="@string/edtxtHint_LimiteB"
                android:importantForAutofill="no"
                android:inputType="numberDecimal"
                android:paddingStart="20dp"
                android:paddingEnd="20dp"
                android:singleLine="true"
                android:text="@={datos.limiteB}"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintHeight_default="percent"
                app:layout_constraintHeight_percent=".6"
                app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView3"
                app:layout_constraintWidth_default="percent"
                app:layout_constraintWidth_percent="1" />

        </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:id="@+id/constraintLayout5"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/constraintLayout7"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHeight_default="percent"
        app:layout_constraintHeight_percent=".15"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/constraintLayout6"
        app:layout_constraintWidth_default="percent"
        app:layout_constraintWidth_percent=".8">

        <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
            android:id="@+id/constraintLayout8"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHeight_default="percent"
            app:layout_constraintHeight_percent="1"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintWidth_default="percent"
            app:layout_constraintWidth_percent=".48">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView4"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:gravity="center_vertical"
                android:text="@string/txtView_Error"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/edtxt_Error"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintHeight_default="percent"
                app:layout_constraintHeight_percent=".4"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintVertical_chainStyle="packed"
                app:layout_constraintWidth_default="percent"
                app:layout_constraintWidth_percent="1" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/edtxt_Error"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:background="@drawable/edittext"
                android:digits="0123456789."
                android:ems="10"
                android:hint="@string/edtxtHint_Error"
                android:importantForAutofill="no"
                android:inputType="numberDecimal"
                android:paddingStart="20dp"
                android:paddingEnd="20dp"
                android:singleLine="true"
                android:text="@={datos.error}"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintHeight_default="percent"
                app:layout_constraintHeight_percent=".6"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView4"
                app:layout_constraintWidth_default="percent"
                app:layout_constraintWidth_percent="1" />

        </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

        <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHeight_default="percent"
            app:layout_constraintHeight_percent="1"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="1.0"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintWidth_default="percent"
            app:layout_constraintWidth_percent=".48">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView5"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:gravity="center_vertical"
                android:text="@string/txtView_Decimales"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/edtxt_Decimales"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintHeight_default="percent"
                app:layout_constraintHeight_percent=".4"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintVertical_chainStyle="packed"
                app:layout_constraintWidth_default="percent"
                app:layout_constraintWidth_percent="1" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/edtxt_Decimales"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:background="@drawable/edittext"
                android:digits="0123456789"
                android:ems="10"
                android:hint="@string/edtxtHint_Decimales"
                android:importantForAutofill="no"
                android:inputType="number"
                android:paddingStart="20dp"
                android:paddingEnd="20dp"
                android:singleLine="true"
                android:text="@={datos.decimales}"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintHeight_default="percent"
                app:layout_constraintHeight_percent=".6"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView5"
                app:layout_constraintWidth_default="percent"
                app:layout_constraintWidth_percent="1" />

        </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Cuando ingreso los datos y le doy a Calcular tiene que mostrarse una tabla con los resultados pero ademas de mostrarse la tabla se sigue mostrando el primer formulario para ingresar los datos cuando en realidad este no deberia estar visible:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Codigo xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".view.metodo_biseccion.fragment_biseccion.FragmentBiseccionResultado">

    <TableLayout
        android:id="@+id/tblLayoutResult"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHeight_default="percent"
        app:layout_constraintHeight_percent="1"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintWidth_default="percent"
        app:layout_constraintWidth_percent="1">

    </TableLayout>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Investigando un poco encontre que la solucion seria agregar `.addToBackStack(null)` ya lo hice y no funciona, se sigue mostrando los dos fomularios en uno. Tambien trate de establecer que cuando el fragmento llame a su estado `onStop()` se haga invisible y tampoco funciona, y aunque funcionara aqui surge otro problema y es de que al girar el dispositivo, a parte de que todos los fragmentos almacenados en el stack se hacen visibles, estos vuelven a llamar a sus estados de `onCreate`, `onStart()`(lo se porque coloque un `toast` en cada uno de sus estados y verdaderamente se vuelven a construir) y esto seria un problema grave ya que todos los metodos se volverian a ejecutar y seria un problema de rendimiento y podria generar errores. Alguien sabe como solucionar esto?. Lo que necesito es de que no solamente los fragmento ya reemplazados(`.replace`) permanezcan ocultos sino de que estos ya no se vuelvan a llamar. El codigo que estoy utilizando para realizar mis cambio de fragmentos es:

```
getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragmentContainer, fragmentBiseccionResultado).addToBackStack(null).commit();
```

Actividad Principal:

```
public class ActivityBiseccion extends AppCompatActivity implements InterfaceActivityBiseccion {
private FragmentBiseccion fragmentBiseccion;
private FragmentBiseccionResultado fragmentBiseccionResultado;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_biseccion);

    init();
}

private void init(){
    getSupportActionBar().setTitle("Metodo Biseccion");
    fragmentBiseccion = new FragmentBiseccion();
    fragmentBiseccionResultado = new FragmentBiseccionResultado();
    fragmentBiseccion.setInterfaceActivityBiseccion(this);
    getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(R.id.fragmentContainer, fragmentBiseccion).commit();
}

@Override
public void onFragmentInteraction(Uri uri) {

}

@Override
public void replaceFragmentToBiseccionResultado() {
    getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragmentContainer, fragmentBiseccionResultado).addToBackStack(null).commit();
}
```

Codigo java de la primera pantalla (FragmentBiseccion.java):

```
public class FragmentBiseccion extends Fragment implements InterfaceModelBiseccion {
private static final String ARG_PARAM1 = "param1";
private static final String ARG_PARAM2 = "param2";
private String mParam1;
private String mParam2;
private OnFragmentInteractionListener mListener;
private FragmentBiseccionBinding binding;
private ModelBiseccion modelBiseccion;
private InterfaceActivityBiseccion interfaceActivityBiseccion;

public FragmentBiseccion() { /* Required empty public constructor */ }


public static FragmentBiseccion newInstance(String param1, String param2) {
    FragmentBiseccion fragment = new FragmentBiseccion();
    Bundle args = new Bundle();
    args.putString(ARG_PARAM1, param1);
    args.putString(ARG_PARAM2, param2);
    fragment.setArguments(args);
    return fragment;
}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    if (getArguments() != null) {
        mParam1 = getArguments().getString(ARG_PARAM1);
        mParam2 = getArguments().getString(ARG_PARAM2);
    }
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    binding = DataBindingUtil.inflate(inflater, R.layout.fragment_biseccion, container, false);
    init();
    return binding.getRoot();
}

public void setInterfaceActivityBiseccion(InterfaceActivityBiseccion interfaceActivityBiseccion) { this.interfaceActivityBiseccion = interfaceActivityBiseccion; }

private void init(){
    modelBiseccion = ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(ModelBiseccion.class);
    modelBiseccion.setContext(getContext());
    modelBiseccion.setInterfaceModelBiseccion(this);
    binding.setDatos(modelBiseccion);
    binding.setEvento(modelBiseccion);
}

public void onButtonPressed(Uri uri) {
    if (mListener != null) {
        mListener.onFragmentInteraction(uri);
    }
}

@Override
public void onAttach(Context context) {
    super.onAttach(context);
    if (context instanceof OnFragmentInteractionListener) {
        mListener = (OnFragmentInteractionListener) context;
    } else {
        throw new RuntimeException(context.toString() + " must implement OnFragmentInteractionListener");
    }
}

@Override
public void onDetach() {
    super.onDetach();
    mListener = null;
}

@Override
public void OnClickCalcular() { interfaceActivityBiseccion.replaceFragmentToBiseccionResultado(); }

public interface OnFragmentInteractionListener { void onFragmentInteraction(Uri uri);}
}
```

Codigo Java de la segunda pantalla (FragmentBiseccionResultado.java)

```
public class FragmentBiseccionResultado extends Fragment {
// the fragment initialization parameters, e.g. ARG_ITEM_NUMBER
private static final String ARG_PARAM1 = "param1";
private static final String ARG_PARAM2 = "param2";
private String mParam1;
private String mParam2;
private TableRow row;
private TextView textView;
private OnFragmentInteractionListener mListener;
private FragmentBiseccionResultadoBinding binding;

public FragmentBiseccionResultado() { /* Required empty public constructor */ }

public static FragmentBiseccionResultado newInstance(String param1, String param2) {
    FragmentBiseccionResultado fragment = new FragmentBiseccionResultado();
    Bundle args = new Bundle();
    args.putString(ARG_PARAM1, param1);
    args.putString(ARG_PARAM2, param2);
    fragment.setArguments(args);
    return fragment;
}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    if (getArguments() != null) {
        mParam1 = getArguments().getString(ARG_PARAM1);
        mParam2 = getArguments().getString(ARG_PARAM2);
    }
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    binding = DataBindingUtil.inflate(inflater, R.layout.fragment_biseccion_resultado, container, false);
    init();
    return binding.getRoot();
}

private void init(){
    getActivity().setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++){
        row = new TableRow(getContext());
        for(int j = 0; j < 10; j++){
            textView = new TextView(getContext());
            textView.setPadding(10,10,10, 10);
            textView.setText("Celda " + i + " " + j);

            row.addView(textView);
        }
        binding.tblLayoutResult.addView(row);
    }
}

public void onButtonPressed(Uri uri) {
    if (mListener != null) {
        mListener.onFragmentInteraction(uri);
    }
}

@Override
public void onAttach(Context context) {
    super.onAttach(context);
    if (context instanceof OnFragmentInteractionListener) {
        mListener = (OnFragmentInteractionListener) context;
    } else {
        throw new RuntimeException(context.toString() + " must implement OnFragmentInteractionListener");
    }
}

@Override
public void onDetach() {
    super.onDetach();
    mListener = null;
}

public interface OnFragmentInteractionListener {
    void onFragmentInteraction(Uri uri);
}
}
```

Comment: Un poco extraño ya que estas realizando un .replace(), revisa si esto se esta realizando en todos los casos en tu aplicación. @Leonidas Agrega un poco más de código para saber en que caso reemplazas el fragmento

Comment: Este es el unico formulario que hize, ya que me quede atrapado en ese problema.

Comment: Agrega un poco más de código por favor, para saber en que caso reemplazas el fragmento @Leonidas

Comment: Listo, espero que logres entender ya que estoy utilizando el patron arquitectonico MVVM y databinding.

Answer (score 0):

Al dar clic y llamar el método `OnClickCalcular()` también se llama el método:

```
@Override
public void replaceFragmentToBiseccionResultado() {
    getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragmentContainer, fragmentBiseccionResultado).addToBackStack(null).commit();
}
```

el problema sucede al almacenar el `Fragment` mediante :

```
.addToBackStack(null)
```

Elimina esa llamada y tu `Fragment` no se almacenará, realizalo de esta forma:

```
public void replaceFragmentToBiseccionResultado() {
    getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragmentContainer, fragmentBiseccionResultado).commit();
}
```

Comment: disculpa la demora, andaba en otras cosas, volviendo a mi proyecto, ya le quite el `addToBackStack(null)` y el problema persiste.